# Ford Transit - ABS Pump no power

Tags: electrical, ford, electronics, abs

I have a 2.2 FWD Ford Transit from 2009. My ABS/ESP and the red brake warning is on as well. When reading the error codes I normally don't get any ABS related codes.

But when erasing the error codes, the lamps turn off, however when hitting the brake hard (while driving) or when turning into a sharp curve it immediately turns on again.
Same happens when I perform a self-test with Forscan, it says "No errors" and lamps go on again. (and stay on, only turn off when erasing the codes)

Once, really only at one time I got this error:

```
===ABS DTC C1B02:15-2B===
Code: C1B02 - Return Pump

Additional Fault Symptom:
 - Circuit Short To Battery Or Open

Status: 
 - DTC Present at Time of Request
 - Malfunction Indicator Lamp is Off for this DTC

Module: Antilock braking system

Diagnostic Trouble Code details

Return Pump

Possible causes are:

ABS Return Flow Pump

Perform these checks

Check the ABS return pump supply voltage.

Check fuses.

Check the connector for damage or contamination.

Check for an open circuit in the wiring harness.

Check for a short circuit in the wiring harness.

Main relay circuit stuck open or stuck closed

The return pump has a internal electrical fault.

Only change the ABS return flow pump if the above checks have been carried out.

 Freeze Frame :
-GLOBTIM: 4146676 sec - Global real time
===END ABS DTC C1B02:15-2B===
```

I never got it again. I recently changed the whole module including the pump to a used module (that is supposed to be checked), after calibrating everything is like before - lamps still on..

I also tested the pump that I extracted itself, it perfectly works when applying power.
So I guess the most probably explanation is:

A broken wire, so that the ABS pump can not draw enough power.

So I would like to check the voltage and the wires. But the amount of pins/cables looks really intimidating and I'm anything but an expert in the field and I also do not have schematics for the ABS system either.

[image]

So I looking for some suggestions what to exactly check for and how to approach checking the cables.

Is there any specific pin just for the pump? Because the module itself has power, I can connect to the ABS module and read out data. I tried starting a ABS bleeding procedure to test the behaviour and I even can hear the solenoid valves "click".

So it would be great to know which pins I need to check!

*(Any other suggestions are of course welcome as well!)*

Thanks in advance!